# The Margin or space outside can't be change to 0

Tags: html, css

This is my css code

```
       .my-works {
         margin-top:0;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: orange;
            }

        .my-works h3 {
            text-align:center;

            }
```

here's my html code

```
    <section class="my-works">

        <h3> MY WORKS </h3>

        <article>
            <h4>My Blog</h4>
            <img src="blog.png">
        </article>

        <article>
            <h4>A Tambay Inspired Flappy Bird - Yotni Bird</h4>
            <img src="flappybird.png">
        </article>

    </section>
```

This is the result of the site

[image: problem]

I already change the css margin to 0 but still it has space between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `h3` to have `margin-top:0`

```
.my-works h3 {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Not the container

Comment: oh yes it worked! Thank you! But still, I'm confused  because, why is that the h3 must be set to 0 when the "my-works" class is the container?

Comment: Because the `margin` isn't coming from the container. It is coming from the `h3`. You're seeing the effects of margin collapsing

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you webmaster.

Comment: Most HTML elements are given default `margin` values by the browser. You can look into CSS resets to remove them and start from scratch. Remember if you found the answer useful, you can select it as correct!